# UI controls in Winform application loses tab order when invoked from VB Access

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have added a C# .NET WinForms GUI application as a component library (dll) to an existing solution that has a number of C# projects, these are all WinForms dll libraries. Testing application using a test project works great and all tab orders behave as expected. There is an interface within the solution allowing components in the solutions to be invoked from VB Access. The strange problem is that when the Form is invoked from VB Access the tab orders are lost.
The same exact application when launched using a test project within the solution works perfectly.
Also, the same WinForms Application when launched using a process works.

Due to exiting deployment, I need to invoke the Winform applicaiton/component from VB Access using
exiting interop Invoke and don't understand why the tab orders are lost. Everything else works fine except the tab orders. There is no issue with the tab orders definition as I have verified it using the test app and launching it using a process call. The issue seems related only to Invoke from VB Access and I haven't been able to find anything on this issue.

Comment: This is by design.  A call to Application.Run() or a form's ShowDialog() method is required to ensure the Winforms message loop is active.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that was the problem and now it is resolved.